# How can I perform conditional operations depending on other rows in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to the following. There are many `Strain`s and `Day`s.

```
  Strain Day Parasite Rep1 Rep2 Rep3
1    KO1   1      Red    5    6    7
2    KO1   1    Green    6    7    8
3    KO1   1     Both    3    1    5
4    KO2   1      Red    5    6    7
5    KO2   1    Green    6    7    8
6    KO2   1     Both   10   10   10
```

Some parasites are red, some are green, and some are both. I'd like to create a new data frame where the new `Red <- Red+Both`, and the new `Green <- Green+Both` (for `Rep1`, `Rep2` and `Rep3`).

Specifically, if `Parasite=="Red" | Parasite=="Green"`, then add to `Rep1` the value of `Rep1` for `Parasite=="Both`, from the same `Strain` and `Day`. Repeat for `Rep2` and `Rep3` for this row, then repeat for all other `Parasite=="Red" | Parasite=="Green"`. For the final data frame, don't include rows where `Parasite=="Both`.

The new data frame should look like this.

```
  Strain Day Parasite Obs1 Obs2 Obs3
1    KO1   1      Red    8    7   12
2    KO1   1    Green    9    8   13
3    KO2   1      Red   15   16   17
4    KO2   1    Green   16   17   18
```

Comment: does every strain have a "both" value. and if so, is it always located at the third position?

Comment: @road_to_quantdom Yes, every `Strain` and `Day` will have a triplet of all colours including `Both`. It *is* always in the third position, so that will work okay for this example, but I'm also looking for a more generic answer that will work in all cases. I guess I could always sort it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` for this.  We create a vector of column names that start with 'Rep' using `grep` ('nm1').  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Strain', 'Day', we subset the columns 'nm1' (`.SD[, nm1, with=FALSE]`).  This can be used along with 'Parasite' as input for `Map`.  Subset each column in `.SD[, nm1, with=FALSE]` based on values in 'Parasite' that are either 'Red' or 'Both' and 'Green' or 'Both'. get the `sum` of each of the columns within the `Map`.  Then, we create the 'Parasite' column by recycling the 'Red', 'Green' string and change the column names if required (`setnames(..`).

```
 library(data.table)
 nm1 <- grep('^Rep', names(df1), value=TRUE)
 res <- setDT(df1)[, Map(function(x,y) c(sum(x[y %in% c('Red', 'Both')]), 
                                    sum(x[y %in% c('Green', 'Both')])),
             .SD[, nm1, with=FALSE], list(Parasite)), .(Strain, Day)
                 ][, Parasite:=c('Red', 'Green')][]
setnames(res, 2:4, paste0('Obs', 1:3))
res
#   Strain Day Obs1 Obs2 Obs3 Parasite
#1:    KO1   1    8    7   12      Red
#2:    KO1   1    9    8   13    Green
#3:    KO2   1   15   16   17      Red
#4:    KO2   1   16   17   18    Green

str(res)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ Strain  : chr  "KO1" "KO1" "KO2" "KO2"
# $ Obs1    : int  1 1 1 1
# $ Obs2    : int  8 9 15 16  
# $ Obs3    : int  7 8 16 17
# $ Rep3    : int  12 13 17 18
# $ Parasite: chr  "Red" "Green" "Red" "Green"
```

---

Or we can use `lapply`

```
res1 <- setDT(df1)[, c(list(Parasite=c('Red', 'Green')),
         lapply(.SD[, nm1, with=FALSE], function(x) 
                 c(sum(x[Parasite %in% c('Red', 'Both')]), 
                 sum(x[Parasite %in% c('Green', 'Both')])))), 
                        .(Strain, Day)]
setnames(res1, nm1, paste0('Obs', 1:3))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Strain = c("KO1", "KO1", "KO1", "KO2", "KO2", 
"KO2"), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Parasite = c("Red", 
"Green", "Both", "Red", "Green", "Both"), Rep1 = c(5L, 6L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 10L), Rep2 = c(6L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 10L), Rep3 = c(7L, 
8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 10L)), .Names = c("Strain", "Day", "Parasite", 
"Rep1", "Rep2", "Rep3"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thank you. It'll take me a few days of reading to understand all of this, but I'll get back in a little while.

Comment: Yes, and upvote of course. (I'm fairly active in other SE sites.)

Comment: I have a problem that `res` is a `data.table`, not a `data.frame`. I tried converting it to a `data.frame` with `setDF(res)`. However, the numbers are `list`s, not `numeric`.

Comment: Also, my original data.frame was converted to a data.table.

Comment: @Sparhawk I changed `list` to `c`.  It created the trouble.  Now, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks that works (although I still needed `setDF(res)` at the end).

Comment: @Sparhawk If you need to do this in base R, it can be done with `split` and `Map`, then you don't need the conversions back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your data is stored in the variable `data`

```
library(data.table)
# that way we can use "by=StrainDay" later on
data$StrainDay <- paste(data$Strain,data$Day,sep="_")

# this will sum up the green parasites and both by StrainDay which we created earlier
res1 <- data[,list("Obs1"=sum(Rep1[Parasite=="Green" | Parasite=="Both"]),
                   "Obs2"=sum(Rep2[Parasite=="Green" | Parasite=="Both"]),
                   "Obs3"=sum(Rep3[Parasite=="Green" | Parasite=="Both"]),
                   "Parasite"="Green"),
             by=StrainDay]
# this will sum up the red parasites and both by StrainDay as well
res2 <- data[,list("Obs1"=sum(Rep1[Parasite=="Red" | Parasite=="Both"]),
                   "Obs2"=sum(Rep2[Parasite=="Red" | Parasite=="Both"]),
                   "Obs3"=sum(Rep3[Parasite=="Red" | Parasite=="Both"]),
                   "Parasite"="Red"),
             by=StrainDay]
# the output isn't in the same order as yours, but you can fix that easily
res <- rbind(res1,res2)

res$Strain <- unlist(strsplit(res$StrainDay,"_"))[seq(1,nrow(res),2)]
res$Day <- unlist(strsplit(res$StrainDay,"_"))[seq(2,nrow(res),2)]

res$StrainDay <- NULL

> res
#   Obs1 Obs2 Obs3 Parasite Strain Day
#1:    9    8   13    Green    KO1   1
#2:   16   17   18    Green    KO2   1
#3:    8    7   12      Red    KO1   1
#4:   15   16   17      Red    KO2   1
```

Comment: Thank you. It'll take me a few days of reading to understand all of this, but I'll get back in a little while.